# Want to auto populate city and state from an entered U.S. zip code, WordPress

Tags: wordpress, addresses, postcode

I am a complete newbie to CiviCRM and hoping to use this platform with WordPress to replace an antiquated CRM (even has comments for displaying properly on netscape). One of the desired features is to auto populate the city and state when a user enters a U.S. zip code.

I see something similar here. https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-region-lookup. However, it doesn't look like it is being maintained for recent versions of CiviCRM. Is this a red flag? Also noted that this is for Drupal and I would need a WordPress version.

I did manage to find Administer > System Settings > Extensions but I don't see anything there similar to what I need.

I also see that USPS has Web Tools API with this functionality but wouldn't know how to implement that for CiviCRM within Wordpress. https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm#_Toc410982991

All ideas, suggestions and help would be very welcome.

Thanks so much in advance!

D

Comment: Hi. Did you ever get anything working? In our case we will only have first, last, email and ZIP on the form, so we don't need to be filling the Profile fields for State and City, just need this happening when the record is saved/created.

Answer (score 3):

I only now stumbled on this question, so will copy-paste my response from the forum:

I am the developer of civicrm-region-lookup. I use it on CiviCRM 4.6, and it would require a small fix for CiviCRM 4.7, but it should work otherwise.

Although it is probably not the most user-friendly solution. It was meant to be flexible and vendor-neutral (i.e. not rely on specific paid sites for the data, make it possible to manage your own mappings).

For the US, you would need to import a list of postcodes via phpmyadmin, then configure the correct mapping in the admin settings (i.e. to set the field names so that the postcode field sets the city, but you might need an additional custom Javascript hook to set the state as well, which is not ideal, but not very complicated either).

There may be simpler solutions out there, especially for the US. If you decide to use this extension, I will be happy to provide some support on this forum if you run into issues.

Reference: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=37098.0

See also the comments from petednz on the forum.

Comment: Hi LakeGirlMT and bgm. I'm very interested in getting autopopulate of city, county, state based on US ZIP code entered/added. Will take a look at the region lookup extension and the USPS API as places to start.

Comment: Curious if there has been any updates on this? I just installed the counties extension (https://aghstrategies.com/counties) and it would be nice if we could auto-populate that counties field on our contacts based on the zip.

Comment: We ended up going with SuiteCRM after running into a few roadblocks with CiviCRM.